# bash trap with `bash` and `source`

Tags: bash, signals

I have simple script which can be summarized as

```
#!/bin/bash

function no_ctrlc()
{
    echo "something"
    exit
}

trap no_ctrlc SIGINT

while true
do
    echo -n .
    sleep 5
done
```

Do you know why if I call `source script.sh` the trap is not working (not only it's not calling `no_ctrlc` but also ctrl+c is not having effects at all), while if calling `bash script.sh` or even `./script.sh` (after a proper `chmod +x`) the trap is working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/a/176788)

Comment: How is this actually affecting the signals? Are you telling me that, when using `source`, `trap` is reading the signals of the current "shell" process?

Comment: It works as expected for me, whether sourcing, executing, or `bash script.sh`. Are you sourcing this interactively or in a script? Are you running asynchronously? `man bash`: “When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT”. More info in “SIGNALS”.

Comment: If you _source_ the script in you interactive bash, and then hit control-C, the trap should be executed. If you see a different behaviour, please explain what exactly you did, so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: I am working in an interactive bash shell: `echo $SHELL` is returning `/bin/bash`.
You can clearly see that with bash everything is ok: pressing `ctrl+c` after calling `bash test.sh` returns `...^Csomething`. Instead doing it when sourcing `source test.sh` returns `..^C...^C....^X...^Z..^\Quit: 3`.
Not only `ctrl+c` is not captured but also all the others signals are ignored (probably due to what @jared_mamrot suggested).